# Removing function call from Gridview TemplateField programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a gridview that, because of screen space issues, truncates text in one of the templatefields (label control).

What I'm trying to do is, export that gridview to an excel file, but I'd like that field not to be truncated when exporting.

Is there a way to do this?  Basically I'm trying to remove the function call programmatically.

This is the code of the TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField Header-Text="Notes">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="lblNotes" runat="server" Text='<# TruncateText(Eval("Notes"),60) %>'></asp:label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You mean while exporting, you are reading the cell value from rendered HTML gridview cells ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add any sort of Flag variable to your page, and if this variable is true for example, don't call the function.

sorry, I'm quickly answering this, let me know if you need more details or some code to follow.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the full text also hidden in another label.

Then in the below sample URL, inside the `PrepareGridViewForExport` method hide the truncated Label and Show the full content label.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/exportxl_asp2_dc11032006003657AM/exportxl_asp2_dc.aspx